# How to create a 2d histogram that draws its colors from a 2d colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, colormap, color-space

### Old Question: How to create an HSL colormap in matplotlib with constant lightness?

According to [matplotlib's colormap documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#lightness-of-matplotlib-colormaps), the lightness values of their default colormaps are not constant. However, I would like to create a colormap from the [HSL color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) that has a constant lightness. How can I do that?

I get that generally, [it's not that hard to create your own colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html), but I don't know how to do this while satisfying the lightness criterion. Maybe this can be done by reverse-engineering the code from the colormap documentation?

### Solution

I think I found a way to do that, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10791901/5472354). First of all, working in the HSL color space turned out to be not the best idea for my overal goal, so I switched to HSV instead. With that, I can load the preferred colormap from matplotlib, create a set of RGB colors from it, transform them into HSV, set their color value constant, transform them back into RGB and finally create a colormap from them again (which I can then use for a 2d histogram e.g.).

### Background

I need a colormap in HSV with a constant color value because then I can uniquely map colors to the RGB space from the pallet that is spanned by hue and saturation. This in turn would allow me to create a 2d histogram where I could color-code both the counts (via the saturation) and a third variable (via the hue).

In the MWE below for example (slightly changed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71235329/5472354)), with a colormap with constant color value, in each bin I could use the saturation to indicate the number of counts (e.g. the lighter the color, the lower the number), and use the hue to indicate the the average `z` value. This would allow me to essentially combine the two plots below into one. (There is also [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/add-alpha-to-an-existing-matplotlib-colormap) on adding alpha values to a 2d histogram, but this wouldn't work in this case I think.)

Currently, you still need both plots to get the full picture, because without the histogram for example, you wouldn't be able to tell how significant a certain `z` value in a bin might be, as the same color is used independently of how many data points contributed to it (so judging by the color, a bin with only one data point might look just as significant as a bin with the same color but that contains many more data points; thus there is a bias in favor of outliers).

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# make data: correlated + noise
n = 1000
x, y = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, (2, n))
z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) + np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)

bins = 20
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(7, 3), constrained_layout=True)
_, _, _, img = axs[0].hist2d(x, y, bins=bins)
fig.colorbar(img, ax=axs[0])
axs[0].set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='histogram')

sums, xbins, ybins = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins, weights=z)
counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)
with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
    # suppress possible divide-by-zero warnings
    img = axs[1].pcolormesh(xbins, ybins, sums / counts, cmap='inferno')
fig.colorbar(img, ax=axs[1], label='z')
axs[1].set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='weighed by z')
fig.show()
```

### Remaining part of the issue

Now that I managed to find a way to create colormaps with constant color value, what remains is figuring out how to have the 2d histogram drawing from a 2d colormap. Since 2d histograms create an instance of a [`QuadMesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh), and apparently you can set its facecolors, maybe that is a way to go about it, but I haven't figured out how. Below is my implementation of creating the 2d colormap at least:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb, rgb_to_hsv, ListedColormap

# make data: correlated + noise
np.random.seed(100)
n = 1000
x, y = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, (2, n))
z = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) + np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)

bins = 20
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(8, 3), constrained_layout=True)
_, _, _, img = axs[0].hist2d(x, y, bins=bins)
fig.colorbar(img, ax=axs[0], label='N')
axs[0].set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='histogram')

# creating the colormap
inferno = cm.get_cmap('inferno')
hsv_inferno = rgb_to_hsv(inferno(np.linspace(0, 1, 300))[:, :3])
hsv_inferno[:, 2] = 1
rgb_inferno = hsv_to_rgb(hsv_inferno)

# plotting the data
sums, xbins, ybins = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins, weights=z)
counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)
with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
    # suppress possible divide-by-zero warnings
    img = axs[1].pcolormesh(
        xbins, ybins, sums / counts, cmap=ListedColormap(rgb_inferno)
    )
axs[1].set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y', title='weighed by z')

# adding the custom colorbar
S, H = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:300j]
V = np.ones_like(S)
HSV = np.dstack((H, S, V))
HSV[:, :, 0] = hsv_inferno[:, 0]
# HSV[:, :, 2] = hsv_inferno[:, 2]
RGB = hsv_to_rgb(HSV)
z_min, z_max = np.min(img.get_array()), np.max(img.get_array())
c_min, c_max = np.min(counts), np.max(counts)
axs[2].imshow(
    np.rot90(RGB), origin='lower', extent=[c_min, c_max, z_min, z_max],
    aspect=14
)
axs[2].set_xlabel("N")
axs[2].set_ylabel("z")
axs[2].yaxis.set_label_position("right")
axs[2].yaxis.tick_right()

# readjusting the axes a bit
fig.show()  # necessary to get the proper positions
pos = axs[1].get_position()
pos.x0 += 0.065
pos.x1 += 0.065
axs[1].set_position(pos)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What comes to my mind is to interpolate in the 2D colorspace you already defined. Running the following code after your last example with `n=100000` for smoother images.

```py
from scipy import interpolate 

z = np.divide(sums, counts, where=counts != 0);
points = np.mgrid[
    0:np.max(counts):1j*RGB.shape[0], # use counts for the first axis
    0:np.max(z):1j*RGB.shape[1], # use sum in for the second axis
]
# arrange points in a N x 2 array
points = np.stack(points, axis=2).reshape(-1, 2)
# arrange the colors in a N x 3 array
values =  RGB.reshape(-1, 3) # use your 2D colormap as values

# Creates an interpolator from (..., 2) to (..., 3)
cmap2d = interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(
    points, values
)
# stack counts and sums in an array of (n1, n2, 2)
cpoints = np.stack([counts, z], axis=2)
# gets an (n1, n2, 3) array
img = cmap2d(cpoints)
# plot the img as a RGB image
plt.imshow(img, extent=[xbins[0], xbins[-1], ybins[0], ybins[-1]])
```

This is what you get
[image]

For logarithmic scale you apply the logarithm to the limits but use equally space grid. When interpolating you use the logarithm of the coordinate.

```
from scipy import interpolate 

z = np.divide(sums, counts, where=counts != 0);
points = np.mgrid[
    # apply log to the limits from 1/e to max(count)
    -1:np.log(np.max(counts)):1j*RGB.shape[0], # use counts for the first axis
    0:np.max(z):1j*RGB.shape[1], # use sum in for the second axis
]
# arrange points in a N x 2 array
points = np.stack(points, axis=2).reshape(-1, 2)
# arrange the colors in a N x 3 array
values =  RGB.reshape(-1, 3) # use your 2D colormap as values

# Creates an interpolator from (..., 2) to (..., 3)
cmap2d = interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(
    points, values
)
# stack counts and sums in an array of (n1, n2, 2)
# apply log to the values
cpoints = np.stack([np.log(np.maximum(counts, 1)), z], axis=2)
# gets an (n1, n2, 3) array
img = cmap2d(cpoints)
# plot the img as a RGB image
plt.imshow(img, extent=[xbins[0], xbins[-1], ybins[0], ybins[-1]])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you! Why are you using `sums` for your `points` grid though? The x-axis of the colormap are the `counts`, that is correct, but the y-axis should be the `z` values.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is almost correct now. The final image should be turned by 90° counterclockwise though to match with the histogram. But I guess instead of rotating the image (using `np.rot90` again e.g.), this could probably be handled at some previous step of the image assembly. Also, for the general case, I believe the `points` grid should go from `np.min(z):np.max(z)`. (There is also a stray `;` at the end of the line where you define `z`.)

Comment: Maybe one more request: currently, the saturation (`S`) values are linearly spaced. Do you know how this could be done logarithmically?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is another issue. This only works if `x` and `y` have the same "scale". E.g. if `x = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, n)` and `y = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, n)/1000`, the plot is completely sqished.

Comment: Ok, nvm. I found a way to deal with this by setting `aspect=(xbins[-1]-xbins[0])/(ybins[-1]-ybins[0])` in `plt.imshow`.